# Why is the file field empty? React file upload to .net core web api

Tags: reactjs, axios, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a picture to the back end, the web api works when I test it with postman. The image file is empty when I send it from the front end.

this code bellow sending from form data

```
  const submit = useCallback(
    async (values: PostExtensions) => {
      debugger;
      setLoading(true);

      const date = dayjs(values.date );
      values.date = dayjs(date , "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z").format();
      var imgdata = values.file![0];

      const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
      formdata.append("postId", values.postId!);
      formdata.append("file", imgdata);
      formdata.append("userId", values.userId!);
      formdata.append("projectId", values.projectId!);
      formdata.append("date", values.date!);

      for (var pair of Array.from(formdata.entries())) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + JSON.stringify(pair[1]));
      }

      await entitySubmit({ // entity submit is axios extensions for my crud op and state op.
        values: formdata,
        dispatch: dispatch,
        returndata: true,
        links: [
          {
            type: 0,
            link: "gider/addpost",
            actionType: ActionType.add_Post,
            method: "POST",
          },
          {
            type: 1,
            link: "gider/editpost",
            actionType: ActionType.edit_Post,
            method: "POST",
          },
        ],
        id: "postId",
      })
        .then((res) => {
          if (res) {
            console.log(res);
            setLoading(false);
            setShow({ ...show, modal: false });
          } else {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        })
        .catch(() => setLoading(false));
      return null;
    },
    [show, dispatch]
  );
```

The file comes into values.file, but it turns into this shape when sending it.

file field always get this --> file, "[object Object]"

I could'nt post file object to server

[image]

**EDIT 1:** I found the solution, when I try this code

`var imgdata = new Blob([values.file![0]], {type : 'image/jpeg'})`,

it seems like work, but What if the image is not jpg extension?

Comment: what is values object?

Comment: Does your input tag as type attribute as file ?

Comment: Please add some more code.. do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form element?

Comment: content-type : "multipart/form-data" not working,

Comment: I found the solution, when I try this code var imgdata = new Blob([values.file![0]], {type : 'image/jpeg'}),  it seems like work, but What if the image is not jpg extension?